# How often should UDP packets be sent?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, udp, frame-rate

I have written an application in Python 2.7 and I'm using UDP sockets to implement networking capabilities. Though my application is not a game, I would consider it a game for networking purposes because the screen is redrawn 60 times per second.

I do not need *extreme* precision, so I don't need to send a ton of packets per second, but the way I have implemented networking causes fellow users to look "choppy" if there aren't a fair amount of packets sent per second.

After some research and fiddling, I've decided to send one packet every 50 milliseconds. This makes the other users look fairly "smooth" for a while, but after about a minute they get more and more choppy, eventually to the point of no updates happening.

How am I supposed to implement networking like the networking done in video games? It seems like I am fundamentally missing something.

Comment: you should never sync your updates to the network. your "game" would freeze if there's any network service breaks. Instead, you keep redrawing the SAME information, and update that information whenever a new packet comes in. no network, you just keep redrawing the same thing. new data comes in, you get a new picture.

Comment: In addition to that, most video games implement some sort of prediction model. Incoming network packets act as corrections to the model, so in theory the game can continue running indefinitely without receiving any new packets. Some games like MMOs have update intervals on the order every second so pretty much every frame they display is a based on a prediction.

Comment: @MarcB That is what I have implemented right now. I essentially just update positions and when packets arrive, but I redraw everything 60 times per second. So I could send one packet per second, but that would mean a networked user would be drawn in one spot for a whole second, and then a packet would be received, updating their location, and then they would be drawn in that location for another second.

Comment: if you've ever played an online game, you probably got rubberbanded at some point. Once a game has you going in a certain direction, it keeps assuming you'll be moving only in that direction until a change in orders arrives. If a packet is lost or missed, eventuall your char gets bounced around the landscape as the client syncs with what the server says your status is.

Comment: @MarcB Ah, I see now.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that the network is getting congested, transmitting old packets that got into the routers' queues and dropping the new packets.

Programming UDP is something of a black art — it requires reacting to network congestion when needed, and slowing down your sending rate.  A simple solution would be to have the receiver send a periodic summary of received packets (say, once per RTT), and reduce your sending rate when you're seeing too many losses.  Ideally, you'd combine that with a precise RTT estimator and reduce your sending rate preemptively when the RTT suddenly increases.